# How can I visualize this data into Python?

Tags: python, plot, graph, data-science

So I want to visualize this data in to below kind of plot in Python.

[image]

```
[('boy', 0.9998371601104736), ('the', 0.9998303651809692), ('s', 0.9998290538787842), ('now', 0.9998087286949158), ('fish', 0.999808669090271), ('up', 0.9998086094856262), ('out', 0.9998055696487427), ('then', 0.9998049736022949), ('him', 0.9998048543930054), ('across', 0.9998047351837158), ('sea', 0.9998030662536621), ('he', 0.999802827835083), ('was', 0.9997997283935547), ('over', 0.9997989535331726), ('head', 0.999798595905304), ('had', 0.999798059463501), ('shark', 0.9997979998588562), ('into', 0.9997978806495667), ('with', 0.9997947216033936), ('man', 0.9997928142547607), ('on', 0.9997923374176025), ('great', 0.9997917413711548), ('water', 0.9997894763946533), ('come', 0.9997884631156921), ('skiff', 0.9997872114181519), ('and', 0.9997856616973877), ('no', 0.9997855424880981), ('when', 0.9997851848602295), ('to', 0.9997830390930176), ('an', 0.9997830390930176)]
```

Comment: What did you try? Got any errors?

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: @Grimmy I'm new in python. As HTML has Canvas and Plotting libraries like plot.ly. I want to see do Python have any such? I want to achieve result which I've shared as Image above in Question. My Data is in formatted code.

Comment: @Frederik.L I've tried Python Matlibplot but don't know how can I use it. I haven't tried because I don't know where to getting started with plotting

Comment: @NeelKadia Please check the provided examples on Matlibplot and update your question with an issue that is blocking you, if any. As it is right now, there is no point trying to answer that question since there isn't any correct answer to give. Any attempt to answer will be a poor opinion-based grocery list. Fix it and it will have a decent chance of getting back to a positive score. Hope that helps.

Comment: You can start by looking through the [matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) to see if there is an example of something close to what you want.  Then you will have to learn how it was achieved so you can adapt it to your purpose.  There will be a learning curve.

Comment: Your example data isn't relevant to the *graph* you showed us.

Comment: @wwi It is. It seems drawing a vector of X(Boy) and Y(Value) we can plot a scatter graph. Above graph was just an inspiration to plot the points. I did using matlibplot Thanks **wwi**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) and [Basic Plotting with Pylab](http://jakevdp.github.io/mpl_tutorial/tutorial_pages/tut1.html) to understand visualization techniques in general.

If you're deriving these through Machine Learning techniques like LDA, topic modelling you could use [Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) or [pyLDAvis](https://pyldavis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

You should also study this blog [Python data visualization: Comparing 7 tools](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-data-visualization-libraries/) to understand the various possibilities of data visualization using Python.

Comment: Let me take a look. Thanks @coder1532

Comment: @NeelKadia please accept the answer.